# make sure one cpu has written a "double" before another cpu read that "double"?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, arm, cpu

I'm going to running one OS on a dual-core ARM Cortex-A9 CPU (one core runs Linux, the other one has no OS).

In the no-OS side we write a 64-bit `double` to DDR memory, then the Linux side reads it.

Because the CPU has a 32-bit bus to the DDR, the value is transferred in two bus cycles, meaning that the value can be corrupted if the write and read are intermingled on the bus.

What can I do to make it work in a safe manner?

Comment: "one is Linux ,the other one has no os" - then where are the "two different OSes"?

Comment: You will have to implement a cross-core mutex. You can probably look at the implementation of the Linux mutex and copy that.

Comment: @Ezio this is a very bizarre question. What do you mean that one core runs Linux and the second core has no OS? Do you mean you've locked one of the cores for a particular job? How are you performing  locking? Do you have a mutex in place ? The 64-bit interface goes through the SCU and interact with the AXI and you'd end up having to use a spin_lock

Comment: @Ahmed Masud i run the dual-core cpu in AMP(you can wiki it) mode that two core do different things simultaneously.

Comment: @Mats Petersson yes,linux can use spin_lock,but the other core has no os that it cannot aware the spin_lock.

Comment: My point is that you will need to implement a cross-core locking system, and the source code for the suitable locks in Linux would be the right thing to use. I was going to look it up on lxr, but that site seems to be not working - same as it was a few days ago, so not sure what's going on.

Comment: Are you using any of the DMB capabilities in your code on the no-OS side?

Comment: Are those cores have coherency (SCU) enabled? You still can't trust the value will be always correct since a double is two words and it can be reordered depending on alignment on page boundries, cache line size.

Comment: this is what the ldrex/strex pair is for, they are NOT for locking resources (within a single core as they have been incorrectly used in linux and elsewhere) but for protection of memory between the cores in a multicore processor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't specify exactly what your ordering requirements are or how you intend to signal a change - so I'll simply answer the question as stated:

The LDREXD/STREXD instructions are guaranteed to be single-copy atomic if performed on a 64-bit aligned location (and they abort if the location isn't). If you're doing something lockless, that might be of benefit to you. If not, just implement it with a mutex.

Of course, LDREXD/STREXD will only work properly if either of the following is true:

- both Linux and your other software have caches enabled, both cpus have the "SMP" bit set, and both map the shared region as write-back cacehable.
- both Linux and your other software treat the shared region as uncached, and your SoC implements a *global monitor* for the memory device.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear enough, but let's give it a try.

If it is just important for you that the no-Os part always sees a consistent value whenever it reads the data, you just need to do an *atomic* operation. If you would be working with gcc or alike there are builtin functions (e.g `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`) that implement this kind of operation. If not, this can be achieved with a few lines of assembler, you'd easily find references for that. (But be careful on this particular processor this is not just one instruction.)

If you want to have some sort of signalling that the Linux side has written the value, the easiest way would be to implement a lock structure of your own. Since you don't have an OS on one side you would have to implement a busy wait. This again can be done with atomic operations, the gcc builtin  `__sync_lock_test_and_set` would be a good starting point to learn how to achieve this.